# How to represent a data type string as PolarsDataType

Tags: python, python-polars

According to the [documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html) and examples when using `read_csv()`, we can only use `PolarsDataTypes` as the values in the map for dtypes:

```
dtypes: Mapping[str, PolarsDataType] | Sequence[PolarsDataType] | None = None,
```

I have a JSON config where I have a map of the columns and their datatypes but as strings like so:

```
   "columns_dtypes_polars": {
        "pcd": "pl.Utf8",
        "streg": "pl.Int64",
        "oac11": "pl.Utf8",
        "lat": "pl.Float64",
        "long": "pl.Float64",
        "imd": "pl.Int64"
    }
```

When I try to use this after reading into python, the values for PolarsDataTypes are still strings and Polars throws an error. I can't have the raw values in JSON as that would throw an error. I have a ton of fields, so I do need to apply the `dtypes` parameter.

So my main question is how do I convert the string representation `"pl.Int64"` to raw PolarsDataType representation `pl.Int64` so I can use it in the `read_csv()` `dtype` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDK if there is any `polars` way to achieve this. My solution make use of `getattr` builtin function to fetch the attribute from module object.

```py
>>> import polars as pl
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def convert_string_to_polars_dtype(
...     mapping: dict[str, str]
... ) -> dict[str, pl.PolarsDataType]:
...     return {key: getattr(pl, value.split(".")[1]) for key, value in mapping.items()}
... 
>>> 
>>> columns_dtypes_polars = {
...     "pcd": "pl.Utf8",
...     "streg": "pl.Int64",
...     "oac11": "pl.Utf8",
...     "lat": "pl.Float64",
...     "long": "pl.Float64",
...     "imd": "pl.Int64",
... }
>>> 
>>> print(convert_string_to_polars_dtype(columns_dtypes_polars))
{'pcd': Utf8, 'streg': Int64, 'oac11': Utf8, 'lat': Float64, 'long': Float64, 'imd': Int64}
```